# Parameter 'ensemble_size' in autosklearn.regression.AutoSklearnRegressor does not seem to do anything, how to use it correctly?

Tags: python, automl

I am trying to use autosklearn(version 0.4.1) to get an idea in which algorithmic direction to search for my regression problem. I tried it with the boston toy example data from sklearn and it works well (see code below). 
Just it outputs an ensemble of algorithms. Which is good, but I would like it also to tell me which single algorithm is best.

I thought I could achieve this by using the parameter "ensemble_size=1" (or zero) in 
    autosklearn.regression.AutoSklearnRegressor 
but I always get an ensemble with a few weighted algorithms inside. Also if I set "ensemble_size=5" or some number bigger 1 it keeps the ensemble size the same as if I dont set the parameter at all, but not the value that I am giving.

Does anyone know, if I am just using wrong synthax, trying to achieve something that is not possible with the autosklearn package or whether I am missing something else here?

Thank you very much for your answer and best regards,
lgreenalien

```
import sklearn.datasets
import autosklearn.regression 

x, y = sklearn.datasets.load_boston(return_X_y=True)
feature_types = (['numerical'] * 3) + ['categorical'] + (['numerical'] * 9)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(x, y, random_state=1)

automl = autosklearn.regression.AutoSklearnRegressor(
         time_left_for_this_task=120,# in seconds
         per_run_time_limit=30, 
         tmp_folder='tmp_Bostondata',
         output_folder='output_Bostondata',
         )

automl.fit(x_train, y_train, dataset_name='Boston dataset',
       feat_type=feature_types)

predictions = automl.predict(x_test)
```